# The XANES of MnO calculated by VASP is weirdVA

Tags: vasp

I calculated the XANES of the MnO compound following the vaspwiki tutorial (https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/XANES_in_Diamond). But it looks strange and shows great discrepancy with the XANES within the Materials Project which is calculated by FEFF code （https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-19006?chemsys=Mn-O%EF%BC%89).

Attached are the calculated XANES and the INCAR file for VASP calculation. Can someone tell me how to fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQvs4.png)

```
System = MnO XANES
ALGO = FAST
ISMEAR = 0
SIGMA = 0.1
ENCUT = 520
EDIFF = 1E-5
ICORELEVEL = 2
CLNT = 1
CLN = 1
CLL = 0
CLZ = 1.0
CH_LSPEC = .TRUE.
CH_SIGMA = 0.5
NBANDS = 640
LREAL = A
KSPACING = 0.2
```

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us!